# How to tell part of a Rails app to run under www.mydomain.com/blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, heroku

I have an app that runs on Heroku. With this app comes a blog. We want the blog to live under `www.mydomain.com/blog`. On Heroku this is not possible to achieve using 2 separate apps (best we can get is `blog.mydomain.com` however this doesn't work for us, as our app uses wildcard subdomains.

So what we want to do is integrate the two apps (the app and the blog - they are both Rails apps) into one Rails app.

**Questions:**
Is there an easy way to configure routing in such a way that the 'blog part' of the app will listen to routes that start with `/blog` (e.g. the posts controller would respond to `/blog/posts` instead of `/posts`)..?

Your time and insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

```
scope "/blog" do
  resources :posts
end
```

it will map `/blog/posts` to `posts#index`

Answer (score 0):

You can namespace your controllers & routes as described in [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).